# Strange behavior in ASP.net regarding WebControl vs UserControl ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, viewstate, webusercontrol

Ok, I've solved my problem but I don't know why one type of control works and another doesn't.

**The scenario:** I'm working on a custom wizard style page design that was originally done completely with `UserControl`s in C# ASP.Net 4.0. The step that you are viewing  is controlled on server side via control visibilty.

**My problem:** I dislike the `UserControl`s and want to use `WebControl`s as much as possible, though it's not worth my effort to redo the entire thing with `WebControl`s, and new controls are needed to expand the functionality.

**My original solution:** I initially started creating `WebControl`s as needed. This worked fine until I got 2 steps away from a given `WebControl`, where it lost it's `ViewState`. At least I believe that is what happened. It was a `CheckBoxList` and as soon as I was 2 steps away, the `ListItems` disappeared.

**The final solution:** Recreating the same control as a `UserControl` I always have access to the `CheckBoxList` `Items`.

This all seems fairly logical. If a control or one of it's parent's is not visible, it won't be included in the `ViewState` data. I guess the real question is, why does `UserControl` work?

Comment: A control maintains it's Viewstate even if it's `Visible=false`. Easy to check: it is still `Visible=false` after postback. Another example: a GridView keeps it's Rows even though its invisible.

Comment: I literally simply re-wrote the `WebControl` version as a `UserControl`, plugged it with all of the same surrounding logic, and it worked. The only remaining difference I can see is the way `UserControl` is registered. The fact that the `UserControl` is referenced by it's ascx file and the `WebControl` by the assembly. I would really like to understand what could be going on here but I've already wasted the better part of a day on this one stupid control. I'm just looking for suggestions on where to look because I'm out of ideas, and have a working solution.

Comment: This may be related to 'ViewStateMode' and 'EnableViewState' on the page and/or the control. Maybe the UserControl has a different default setting. It may also be simply that your binding code isn't 100% correct as it may rely on some invisible magic provided by UserControls.